# Puzzling behaviour when loading Wine's oleaut32.dll in OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg, dll, wine

I was experimenting with debugging Windows programs under Wine and spotted this weird behaviour.

When I check Wine's oleaut32.dll in OllyDbg I get different values in PE header
compared to that what I could expect analysing the file using hex-editor.
For example number of sections is different.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I have checked Windows version of the library and everything seems to be fine. Looks like it's some kind of Wine specific problem.